# Keras, ImageDataGenerator, cannot identify image file

Tags: tensorflow, keras

So I'm getting an error of "cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7fd2278943b0>" on my validation_dataset apparently.

I'm very new to this, a little lost. Is there anything obvious that I'm doing wrong here?

Any help appreciated, thanks guys.

```
image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255, validation_split=0.2)    

train_dataset = image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=32,
                                                 directory=PATH,
                                                 shuffle=True,
                                                 target_size=(224, 224), 
                                                 subset="training",
                                                 class_mode='categorical')

validation_dataset = image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=32,
                                                 directory=PATH,
                                                 shuffle=True,
                                                 target_size=(224, 224), 
                                                 subset="validation",
                                                 class_mode='categorical')

model.fit_generator(
    train_dataset,
    samples_per_epoch=100,
    nb_epoch=10,
    validation_data=validation_dataset)
```

[image]

Not sure if this has something to do with it also.

Answer (score 0):

There is no parameter such `samples_per_epoch` or `nb_epoch` in `model.fit()`.

Check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) for more clarification on `model.fit()`.

These are named as `steps_per_epoch` and `epochs` as shown below:

```
model.fit(train_dataset, 
          epochs=10, 
          steps_per_epoch=4, #(number of total images)/(batch_size) 
          validation_data=validation_dataset)
```